# .htaccess to deny access to most xml files

Tags: security, .htaccess, joomla

I recently had a Joomla site hacked, so I'm trying to harden the site a bit.
There's a section in the recommended .htaccess that restricts outside access to the xml files that come with extensions. *However, it also keeps my sitemap.xml file from being accessed.*

How do I allow a certain file whiles keeping the rest?

here's the default code:

```
<Files ~ "\.xml$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy all
</Files>
```

and my modification that caused a 500 error:

```
<Files ~ "(?!sitemap)\.xml$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy all
</Files>
```

Comment: Care to specify what the error message is? You'll find it in your error_log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FilesMatch line has an extra "<". It should be:

```
<FilesMatch "(?!sitemap)\.xml$">
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `<FilesMatch>` as documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch)

Also, I think your regex should be `(?<!sitemap)\.xml$` instead. Like this:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!sitemap)\.xml$">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Still cased a 500 error for me.

Comment: Invalid command 'Deny', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided not to mess with the regex.

I added:

```
<Files ~  "sitemap\.xml$">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all  
</Files>
```

afterward and it works like a charm.

Comment: Don't you mane "Deny from all" on line 3?

Comment: no, putting this under the directive to deny all .xml files overrides the directive in this one case. Thus, though not as cool looking as the regex solution, it still works.